# Migrate Discussions from Sharepoint to Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, microsoft-teams

I have a Sharepoint site called "Mouse" and a Teams site called "Mouse" built recently on top of this Sharepoint site. But the discussions which have happened on the Sharepoint site is not being showed on the Teams site. How do I migrate all those discussions to the Teams site?

Comment: Are you talking about SharePoint Team Sites or are you talking about the Office 365 product "Teams" which is partially based on SharePoint Online and Skype for Business?